# Django Password Generator

Tags: django, passwords

I have imported a heap of users and their data to a django project. I need to assign a password to each. Is the such a snippet out there for password generation that will cope with the Django hash and salt?

Comment: It may have changed, but you don't have to "cope with the Django hash and salt" because you can use the [`.set_password()` helper function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) on a `User` object that processes the provided password with your chosen key derivation function and sets the `.password` field/attribute with it.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You can also use the built in function [make_random_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password), but note that it is deprecated as of version 4.2:

```
for user in new_users:
    password = User.objects.make_random_password()
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(update_fields=['password'])
    # email/print password
```

Comment: Also notice that `make_random_password()` accepts keyword arguments `length` and `allowed_chars`.

Comment: `user.save()` to apply changes is missing

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Answer (score 25):

Also you can use `from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string` out of `auth` module, it accepts keyword arguments `length` and `allowed_chars` as well.

Comment: +1. Preferred over User.objects.make_random_password() because it can be run from standalone scripts without having to configure Django settings. I use this for random fixture generation.

Comment: I prefer this because I don't have to interact with any objects to do it. It makes something like a random password generator for a user much easier to do.                             For Instance                                                                                                                         def get_password_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({ "password" : get_random_string() })

Comment: Prefer this one, because `User.objects.make_random_password()` gives error, if it has been inherited.

Answer (score 13):

If you need only a Django`s solutions, then try next:

For generate a normal password try use BaseUserManager.

```
In [341]: from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

# simple password, it length is 10, and it contains ascii letters and digits
In [344]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password()
Out[344]: 'aYMX5Wk7Cu'

In [345]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password()
Out[345]: 'rM7759hw96'

In [346]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password()
Out[346]: 'EkbZxEXyAm'

# passed length of a password
In [347]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(45)
Out[347]: 'dtM9vhSBL9WSFeEdPqj8jVPMH9ytsjPXrkaHUNUQu4zVH'

In [348]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(45)
Out[348]: 'jypVaXuw9Uw8mD4CXtEhtj2E4DVYx23YTMwy8jGTKsreR'

# passed length of a password and symbols for choice
In [349]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(45, 'abcdf')
Out[349]: 'daacbfabfccfdbdddbbcddcfcfbfcdabbaccbfcadbccd'

In [351]: import string

# password contains only digits
In [352]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(50, string.digits)
Out[352]: '00526693878168774026398080457185060971935025500935'

# password contains only ascii symbols in lowercase
In [353]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(50, string.ascii_lowercase)
Out[353]: 'nvftisuezofnashdhlalfmscnmqtvigwjpfwsyycsefekytmar'

# password contains only ascii symbols in uppercase
In [354]: BaseUserManager().make_random_password(50, string.ascii_uppercase)
Out[354]: 'APKSUHHHTAAJCFEUONIXWWAKJGXIBHTQDZBTSYFTPDFOSRYEQR'
```

If you need strong and power password, then try built-in "hashers" in the Django

```
In [355]: from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

In [357]: make_password('')
Out[357]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$JuKXdW3shCjL$PsPJX7Zale5JUBkWpIJI/+QlsuVWhz9Q+GQWVtTpQ/Y='

In [358]: make_password('text')
Out[358]: 'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$lSv8kQ39BHE7$KQC5hRhuphYBXmBrXZBJGC+nxygfNWTDf8zQf/NNgY8='

In [360]: make_password('text', salt=['simething'])
Out[360]: "pbkdf2_sha256$30000$['simething']$D+1vJQx9W2/c9sIz/J+7iEz4d4KFPg/R+0S87n/RKR4="

In [361]: make_password('text', salt=['something'])
Out[361]: "pbkdf2_sha256$30000$['something']$NIcmOkEyg6mnH5Ljt+KvI2LVgZWg6sXS6Rh865rbhSc="
```

Notes:

1. Used Django 1.10 and Python 3.4

Answer (score 5):

Just use the API - `django.contrib.auth.models.User` has a `.set_password()` method. Here's an example (that I haven't tested, but you should get the idea):

```
from random import choice
from string import digits, letters
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def _pw(length=6):
    s = ''
    for i in range(length):
        s += random.choice(digits + letters)
    return s

for user in User.objects.all(): # or .filter(...)
    user.set_password(_pw())
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
import string 
user.set_password(''.join([random.choice(string.digits + string.letters) for i in range(0, 10)]))
user.save()
```