# How to create random password? create_user function

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django Password Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480641/django-password-generator)

```
d = Data.objects.get(key=key)    
User.objects.create_user(username = d.name, email= d.email, password =  password)
```

How to create random password and send this via e-mail to user (`d.email`) ?

Comment: user make_random_password http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481049/188955

Answer (score 35):

in django [`make_random_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password) is a built in method for generating random password

```
my_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
```

it accepts parameters as  `length` and `allowd_chars` with that you can limit the password length and special symbols and numbers

Comment: [`make_random_password`](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15752) is deprecated in Django 4.2.  Use python [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
def view_name(request):
    #make random password
    randompass = ''.join([choice('1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm') for i in range(7)])

    #sending email
    message = "your message here"
    subject = "your subject here"
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['to_email',])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to create random password:

[Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

And to send email.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
password = rand_string
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the password: .'+password,
               'from@example.com', ['someone@gmail.com'],
               fail_silently=False)
```

And you need to define some EMAIL settings in your settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```