# Which is a better alternative to the Django make_random_password Deprecated function?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-auth-models

This [aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480641/django-password-generator) suggests the use of the [make_random_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password), but it is deprecated since Django 4.2. I assume there is a good reason for eliminating this fuction, so what should I use instead?

I searched for alternatives, but could not find any native to Django.
I can create my own solution using hashlib, but should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s very easy to implement this function.

```
import secrets 

def make_random_password(length=10, allowed_chars='abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'):
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))
```

Comment: Yes, I have done something similar, but I was unsure if there was a catch. Some vulnerabilities that I was unaware of. It seemed suspicious to me that they would remove something that is quite simple and easy to maintain, so I was trying to figure out why would an approach like this be problematic, but  I guess it is safe enough for me at this point.